# Will using protocol relative links to other domains from an SSL site require that the external sites have their own SSL?

Tags: apache, https, http-server

If I am configuring `https://foo.example.com` where I have an SSL cert with `CN=foo.example.com`, but `index.html` has includes/images/etc loading from `http://example.othersite/cat.png` and `http://example.somethingelse/script.js`.

Will using protocol agnostic URLs like `//example.somethingelse/script.js` require that a SSL certificate exists for `example.othersite` and `example.somethingelse` or will Apache use my site's cert without causing any warnings/errors in the browser?  Apache 2.2.3, mod_ssl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All those 3 domains are completely independent from each other (even if they are different virtual hosts in the same apache server).
A protocol-relative URL just means "use the same protocol as the current page's".
So, yes, you need to configure https certificates for all those domains. Otherwise the browser may produce a warning saying that some resources in the page were loaded through an unsecure conection.